# Can not find the download Zip button in the GitHub Page

Tags: arduino-zero

I want to download a zip file for the following code from the GitHub. I am pretty new in the GitHub. Can anyone help me how to download the Zip folder for the following code from the GitHub library? I need the folder named StopWatch.Zip to include in the Arduino Zero library.

```
 #ifndef StopWatch_h
#define StopWatch_h
//
//    FILE: StopWatch.h
//  AUTHOR: Rob Tillaart
// PURPOSE: Simple StopWatch library for Arduino
// HISTORY: See StopWatch.cpp
//     URL: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/StopWatchClass
//
// Released to the public domain
//

#define STOPWATCH_LIB_VERSION "0.1.5"

#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

class StopWatch
{
public:
  enum State      { RESET, RUNNING, STOPPED };
  enum Resolution { MILLIS, MICROS, SECONDS };

  explicit StopWatch(const enum Resolution res = MILLIS);
  void start();
  void stop();
  void reset();

  uint32_t value();
  uint32_t elapsed()            { return value(); };

  bool isRunning()              { return _state == StopWatch::RUNNING; };
  enum State state()            { return _state; };
  enum Resolution resolution()  { return _res; };

private:
  enum State _state;
  enum Resolution _res;

  uint32_t _starttime;
  uint32_t _stoptime;

  uint32_t (*_gettime)(void);
  static uint32_t seconds()          { return millis() / 1000; };
};

#endif
// END OF FILE
```

In case, I have attached the link for this Code below.

[Link for the StopWatch.h file](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/StopWatch/StopWatch.h)

Comment: How is this an Arduino question? And this is surely nothing, that you couldn't have found out through googling.

Answer (score -1):

go to https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino and click the "Clone or download" button.

The repository contains many small libraries, not only the StopWatch library.